# Differentiating social surplus function

Tags: probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, discrete-optimization

Can someone possibly explain how to >>make sense<< of the following identity:

$\int \frac{\partial \ max_d \{ u(x,d) + \epsilon(d) \}  }{\partial u(x,d)} q(d\epsilon \lvert x) = \int I\{d = \arg \max_h [u(x,h) + \epsilon(h)] \} q(d \epsilon \lvert x)$

I completely fail to see how taking the partial derivative under the first integral results in the expression with the indicator function?

Comment: You can edit your own question to fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression simply says that when you change a function, u(x,d), you only change the max of that function if you change u(x,d*) where d* is the  argmax of u(x,d) with respect to d.

Comment: Very nice explanation thx Mr. Plum